# Weird Makefile behavior where file needs to be generated first and the compiled

Tags: makefile

I am getting weird behavior in Makefile. Basically for `grammar.aps`, it needs to run `grammar.generate` to create the file first and then `grammar.class` to compile the generated file. If I run the dependencies individually all works. But if I run `grammar.aps` it doesn't work.

```
// Running everything
➜  tests git:(first-follow-tests) ✗ make
scalac -cp .:../../../lib/aps-library-2.12.jar Spec.scala
make: *** No rule to make target 'grammar.class', needed by 'grammar.aps'.  Stop.

// Now running first depdency of `grammar.aps` which is `grammar.generate`
➜  tests git:(first-follow-tests) ✗ make grammar.generate
../../../bin/aps2scala -DCOT -p ../..:../../../base grammar

// Now running second depdency of `grammar.aps` which is `grammar.generate`
➜  tests git:(first-follow-tests) ✗ make grammar.class
scalac -cp .:../../../lib/aps-library-2.12.jar grammar.scala

// Okay but why grammar.aps didn't work? ... Makefile continues further now
➜  tests git:(first-follow-tests) ✗ make                 
scalac -cp .:../../../lib/aps-library-2.12.jar grammar.scala
../../../bin/aps2scala -DCOT -p ../..:../../../base grammar
echo "Building aps"
Building aps
scalac -cp .:../../../lib/aps-library-2.12.jar GrammarUtil.scala
echo "Building GrammarUtil.scala"
Building GrammarUtil.scala

// Same problem with `first.aps`
make: *** No rule to make target 'first.aps', needed by 'FirstSpec.compile'.  Stop.
```

Makefile:

```
SPECS=First Follow
EXAMPLES_PATH=../..
ROOT_PATH=../${EXAMPLES_PATH}
SCALAV=2.12
APSLIB=${ROOT_PATH}/lib/aps-library-${SCALAV}.jar
SCALA_FLAGS=.:${APSLIB}
APS2SCALA=${ROOT_PATH}/bin/aps2scala

.PHONY:
all: $(addsuffix Spec.compile, $(SPECS))

%.class: %.scala
    scalac -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $<

%.generate:
    ${APS2SCALA} -DCOT -p ${EXAMPLES_PATH}:${ROOT_PATH}/base $*

%.aps: %.generate %.class
    echo "Building aps"

%.run: %.class
    @scala -cp ${SCALA_FLAGS} $<

FirstSpec.compile: Spec.class GrammarUtil.compile first.aps FirstSpec.class 
    echo "Building FirstSpec.scala"

FollowSpec.compile: Spec.class GrammarUtil.compile follow.aps FollowSpec.class
    echo "Building FollowSpec.scala"

GrammarUtil.compile: grammar.aps grammar.class GrammarUtil.class
    echo "Building GrammarUtil.scala"

.PHONY:
clean:
    rm -f *.class grammar.scala first.scala follow.scala
```

Comment: You do not need the echos for static rules.  For example removing `echo "Building FirstSpec.scala"` is fine.  You must have a recipe for pattern rules; for example removing `echo "Building aps"` in this makefile will not do what you probably want.  Your error description "it doesn't work" is not actionable.  In any event I recommend you don't try to discuss multiple different issues in the same SO question it just gets confusing.  Pick one thing, fix it, then if you can't figure out the next thing ask about that.

Comment: Updated the question. Thank you

Comment: Where does the file `grammar.scala` come from?  It can't be a source file so it must be generated somehow, but there's nothing in the above makefile that tells make how to generate it.  That's why you get the error about not knowing how to build `generate.class` the first time, when `generate.scala` is not there, but then the next time (after `generate.scala` is created) it works.

Comment: `%.generate` generates the `grammar.scala`

Comment: Do I need to re-order them?

Comment: If it generates both `grammar.generate` and also `gramar.scala`, then you should list both as targets of the pattern rule.  Else how can make know that?  In general it's odd to have a pattern rule without a prerequisite.  How do you know when those output files are out of date and need to be regenerated?  With no prerequisite they will be regenerated _only_ if they don't exist.

Comment: `%.aps: %.generate %.class` what I meant here is first run `grammar.generate` and then file is created then run `grammar.class` which compile the generated file.

Comment: I am not very familiar with Makefile. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I think you should go back to basics.  Have you read the GNU make manual introduction sections?  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html  At the very least we can then have a common vocabulary.  It's confusing to say you "run `grammar.class`"; you "run" programs (like make); you *build* files.  Make is not hard if you start at the beginning.  What are your initial source files that you write?  What commands convert those files, and what are their outputs?  What commands take those outputs as inputs and what outputs do they generate?  Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting weird behavior in Makefile. Basically for grammar.aps, it needs to run grammar.generate to create the file first and then grammar.class to compile the generated file. If I run the dependencies individually all works. But if I run grammar.aps it doesn't work.

You are trying to treat your makefile as if it were a script.  It isn't.  At the most basic level, it is a declarative description of your project that tells `make` how it can construct one or more targets given specific lists of prerequisites for each. Each prerequisite list is only incidentally ordered.  That one prerequisite appears lexically ahead of another has no significance.  It is up to `make` to choose and execute a build plan based on the information in the makefile and the files available.

In particular, `make` performs its analysis of which intermediate targets to build based on the prerequisites available at the start of the run, in light of the declared build rules.  Furthermore, prerequisite build order is constrained only by prerequisites' own prequisites, and it is not necessarily predictable.

However, `make` does give you pretty informative error messages.  For example, this ...

> ```
> make: *** No rule to make target 'grammar.class', needed by 'grammar.aps'.  Stop.
> ```

... is pretty clear: target `grammar.aps` needs to be built, and it has `grammar.class` as a prerequisite, but there is no rule for building `grammar.class`.  That is, there is no rule *having `grammar.class` as its target*.  That building `grammar.generate` would in fact create `grammar.class` is irrelevant because you haven't expressed that to `make`.

You could fix this particular issue by converting your rule for `%.generate` into a rule for `%.class`:

```
%.class:
    ${APS2SCALA} -DCOT -p ${EXAMPLES_PATH}:${ROOT_PATH}/base $*

%.aps: %.class
    echo "Building aps"
```

More generally, you should prefer to write rules with real targets over rules with phony ones.  Phony targets are not necessarily bad, but they are not a viable substitute for real ones.

Comment: But there is already %.class target above %.generate to compile stuff

Comment: I have been spending days trying to fix this Makefile. I truly appreciate any help.